# Show/hide script not working on first click but working thereafter

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to get the “window” div to show/hide with the click of the button in the “line-1” div using this script I pulled from the internet. Nothing happens on the first click but it works fine after that. Any help to get it to work on the first click would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Doug

```
    <div class="line line-1">
        <button class="button button-1" onclick="myFunction()">
            one
        </button>
    </div>

<div id="window">     
    <button class="window-button-1" onclick="myFunction()">
        X
    </button>
</div>

#window {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("window");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 9) /* tab */ {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-focus-outline');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because the initial style x.style.display is empty, I believe because x.style.display checks only for values that have been set programmatically.

Try allowing for that in your check:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("window");
    if (x.style.display !== "block") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

To verify what I am saying, and learn a bit I guess(!), you could always do something like this in your function:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("window");
  console.log(`entering myFunction. x.style.display is [${x.style.display}]`); 
  if (x.style.display !== "block") {
     x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style):

> The style property is used to get as well as set the **inline** style of an element.

The `display` style of your `#window` is first set from css so `x.style.display` will not return `none` at the first click. To make it work, you can use [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("window");
    console.log("x.style.display: " + x.style.display);
    console.log("window.getComputedStyle(x).display: " + window.getComputedStyle(x).display);
    if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#window {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="line line-1">
    <button class="button button-1" onclick="myFunction()">
        one
    </button>
</div>

<div id="window">     
    <button class="window-button-1" onclick="myFunction()">
        X
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I understand but I don't want it to return none on first click but return block. It is initially invisible and didn't appear until I clicked it twice. After that it would toggle visible/invisible.

Comment: I mean at first click, `x.style.display` is not equal to 'none' so the code `x.style.display = "none";` will run. So in the second click,  `x.style.display` will be 'none' and the code `x.style.display = "block";` run.

Comment: You can check snippet in my edited answer for the difference